# How can one zoom in on an img element without zooming in on the whole page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, zooming

This is a regular webpage using Javascript, PHP, CSS, and HTML. Is there a way to have a live web feed or img element execute a zoom like feature (pretty much exactly how google earth or google maps does) when double clicking or double tapping?

If so, is it possible to specify the zoom rate per double click? This is not iOS, but a regular webpage that is optimized for mobile devices.

SO far I've tried using the zoom property with CSS & javascript (targeting the HTML element in question). No luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should try some jQuery plugins for that like http://codecanyon.net/item/pinch-zoomer-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/6623080?ref=designrazzi .

You can check other plugins for image zoom here http://www.webdesignrazzi.com/2014/jquery-zoom-effect-plugins/